# How to know which edition a DotNetNuke site is

Tags: cms

This may be a silly question, but I recently inherited a DotNetNuke site.  Looking in the settings, I can see it's running version 4.09.00 of DNN. Looking at current DNN 5.0 information, there appears to be several editions available (Community, Professional, Enterprise, etc).

So my question is:

- Were these editions also available in the 4.0 version of DNN?
- If so, is there a way to tell which edition the site is running?  I didn't see any immediately obvious designation in the admin areas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DotNetNuke Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke):

> The DotNetNuke Professional Edition was introduced in February 2009 with version 5.0. The DotNetNuke Elite Edition was released in September 2009.

At least these editions were not available in version 4.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It would appear this installation was built before the pro versions existed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into the site with the Host account
2. Mouseover Host from the navigation menu - select Host Settings from the dropdown
3. Version should be the second row, Edition first row

Mine says
DotNetNuke Product: DotNetNuke Community Edition 
DotNetNuke Version: 04.09.05